# Sharing data in multiple User app(User and Admin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-multiple-users

I created the multiple User app in which there are User and Admin.
So i want send the User Enrollment request, if user click on Enroll the form should fillup by the user(Name,email,contact). and after submiting the Data which is filled in the form should be sent to the Admin.
At User Side i have a Activity and At admin side i have a fragment.

note: both(user and admin) are in one app only(multiple user app) with JAVA

Comment: You should create two activities, one for User and one for Admin. Store your form data in local database.

Comment: actually when user sends the enrollment request to admin, the admin should accept and then it should store in FireStore. but I only want to know that by which method i can send form data to Admin